# Timelimit fail with error, but not with timeout

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I am using timelimit to limit the time, during which the program can run. Because I need to return 0 on timeout, I'm using:

```
timelimit -q -t 3600 ./runningfile.sh || true
```

But this returns true even if the runningfile.sh fails. Is there any way to return a non-zero value on command fail, but 0 on timeout? It doesn't necessarily have to use timelimit command.

Comment: What are the valid return codes for runningfile.sh?

Comment: Like any... It's executing some other commands, including make.